# Can I dynamically update the contents of a Google Forms listbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form with two listboxes (among other items). The items in the second listbox depend on the choice made in the first listbox. In pre-App Script forms, I used the method described [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/05/customize-google-docs-forms.html) to capture the form parameters and embed that in my own html and javascript to handle the dependency.

I'd like to move to the new App Script based forms. I know that I could write the form from scratch using App Script. My question is whether I can create a form using the forms interface available from within a spreadsheet, then add a script to handle the dynamic update. In particular, how do I get the listbox objects so that I can add the onChange handler, which in turn would change the contents of the other listbox object?

And for bonus credit, I'd like to populate the listbox contents from a range on a spreadsheet, though this is not essential.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script cannot add any interactivity to a Google Form, because it lacks suitable triggers. The only triggers available for Google Forms are [Open and Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events), where Open means "an editor opens the form to modify it" (pretty much useless). The script has no knowledge about someone filling out the form until the user hits "Submit", and then it's too late.

There is some rudimentary built-in interactivity  in Google Forms: one can [direct a user to a section based on their choice](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en).

Answer (score -2):

Here's everything you'll need except for the trigger for the onChange event. You can do that with a trigger fairly easily.

```
//bonus, gets values from first column of spreadsheet and returns them
function getValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow);
  var values = range.getValues();

  return values;
}

//what you'll need to call initially to create the form, and store id in project properties
function createForm() {
  var values = getValues();
  var form = FormApp.create('Test Form');
  var list = form.addListItem();
  var listItems = list.setChoiceValues(values);
  var formId = form.getId();

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('formId', formId);
}

//use this to update on change event. Trigger can be created for this.
function updateForm() {
  var values = getValues();
  var formId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('formId');
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  var list = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)[0];
  var listItems = list.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: unless I don't understand what you've written, this does not modify an existing Google Form, but creates a new form from scratch.

Comment: only the createForm function creates the form. the updateForm function would update it as needed. Just make sure you store the form Id properly.

Comment: The crux of the question was to change the form based "on the choice made in the first listbox." This script does not do it, and cannot do it, because there is no trigger for "user made a selection on the form".